# Dropdown stops working after being placed in front using z-index

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, listbox, z-index

I've added an Opentable javascript reservation widget to my home page. The module has 3 dropdowns, a calendar, date selector and a time selector. The 2nd 2 dropdowns aren't responsive, even when I use z-index to move them forward to make visible.

I'm thinking I'm doing something wrong with css but can't seem to solve. Or maybe there is a conflict with js?  Not sure.  Any suggestions?  Thanks -- The site is here on a dev server, http://aac.myftpupload.com/

[screenshot of dropdown issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhFcF.jpg)

I'm actually not even sure what code to put up here to share... the script it provided by opentable below, and it comes with a ton of css, which maybe conflicts with my site but I'm not sure:

```
</div><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-9"><div class="vc_column-inner wpex-clr"><div class="wpb_wrapper wpex-vc-column-wrapper wpex-clr " style="min-height:40px;">
<div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_raw_js">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <script src="https://secure.opentable.com/frontdoor/default.aspx?rid=82057&amp;restref=6543&amp;bgcolor=F6F6F3&amp;titlecolor=0F0F0F&amp;subtitlecolor=0F0F0F&amp;btnbgimage=https://secure.opentable.com/frontdoor/img/ot_btn_red.png&amp;otlink=FFFFFF&amp;icon=dark&amp;mode=wide&amp;hover=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </div>
```

Some of the the css for the dropwown is:

```
element.style {
    display: block;
}

#OT_timeList, #OT_partyList {
    width: 108px;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    border-left: 2px solid #b8b4ac;
    border-right: 2px solid #b8b4ac;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #b8b4ac;
    position: absolute;
    top: 34px;
    left: 39px;
    display: none;
}

.entry ul, .entry ol {
    margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

.entry ul {
    list-style: disc;
}

.entry ul, .entry ol {
    margin: 0 0 20px 30px;
}

.OT_navList {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 142px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 200;
    top: 35px;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Users will probably be able to help you faster if you provide relevant code samples within your question.

Comment: Thanks @martieva, I've added some code, but  not sure it's the right part!

Answer (score 0):

In the div "rev_slider_6_1_wrapper" I set `position: relative; z-index: -1;`. This allowed the drop downs to be visible in front of the image and text.

So the div will look like this:

```
<div id="rev_slider_6_1_wrapper" class="rev_slider_wrapper fullwidthbanner-container" style="margin: 0px auto; padding: 0px; max-width: 1000px; height: 400px; overflow: visible; position: relative; z-index: -1;">
```

I'm not sure if this will negatively affect any of your onload effects, but if nothing else it should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, yes that does bring the dropdown upfront, but what I can't figure out is why those two dropdowns don't function on this page.  You can only slect the top item, or scroll from the top item, the rest is kind of "dead".  The script does work on a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

There was some strange code that I guess my template was inserting which caused the dropdowns to fall behind the slider and not function, once I removed this, it worked.

```
css_animation="appear"
```